# "Never" to Positive sentence

Tags: grammar

I know that the interrogative sentence of

> I never drink tea

is **Do I ever drink tea ?**

but what would be the positive form of this sentence?

Is it **I always drink other than Tea** ?

Comment: Why do you think that a sentence must have a positive form? And why do you think there is only one possibility?

Comment: Semantically *and* idiomatically, ***only*** is better than ***always*** to imply *not anything except the thing specified*, but I have to say it doesn't seem very natural to me to use *any* version of ***I only drink [drinks that aren't tea].*** If one item is being excluded, it just seems far more natural to express it using ***never** [excluded item]* rather than ***always / only** [everything except excluded item]*.

Comment: By "positive form" do you mean a way to keep the meaning of the sentence without using *never*, or a way to invert the meaning of the sentence? The former is generally impossible (would be something like *I drink anything but tea*, but that doesn't have the exact same meaning), the latter requires more information (*I always drink tea*? *I sometimes drink tea*? *I drank tea once*?)

Comment: Why do you want to use a positive sentence to describe a clearly negative situation? Can you edit some context into your question?